# Pick functionality from one usercontrol to another

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have dialog which consist of two user controls bind to their models.

[image: Dialog with user controls]

I want to enable user to pick a data point on the chart control from the UserControl1.

I can get the data point on mouse down event of chart control and wan to fill the associated textbox with that value. I am unable to identify the best approach to pass that value back to the UserControl1. Also how will I identify which button has made the call to pick the data point. Note I have to do the same in an MVVM friendly manner.

Comment: If I understood correctly you want each button to enable the user to pick a datapoint for the associated textbox to be filled with ?

Comment: edited the question to reflect that thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not really about `UserControl`, more about ViewModels. I suggest your chart Model (which I guess should be a "ViewModel") could raise an event passing the data point as parameter.

To identify which button has made the call, you can memorise it in your `UserControl` Model (again, ViewModel).